# Is there any way to copy files from azure app service to another azure app service?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I need to copy the files from my app service A to my app service B.

To do this I can simple download the A files over FTP to my computer and upload them to B over FTP.

Is there a way to do this ftp download directly from A to B? I tried azure app service console and kudu power shell but I'm getting the following error:

[image]

I Know that I can clone the entire app service but that's not what a I want.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, azure kudu don't support ftp tool.

Besides, I don't think there's a way to copy files without downloading and re-uploading, at least I found nothing like this in the List of [FTP commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_commands) and no client I have seen so far supported something like this.

You need download it firslty and upload it again.

Here is a workaround, you could use some tools to help you copy files.

These tool also will cpoy the files to local(in temp folder) and upload it again.

For example [WinSCP FTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/) client does support the remote copy.

You could just right click the file after login in and select remote copy tag.

If you want to copy files from A to B in kudu, I suggest you could use git tool to help you copy the files(the entire app service).

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Generate the git url in your web service A.

(1)You could firstly set your deployment username and password.

[image]

(2)Enable local git deploy

[image]

[image]

(3) Find the web service git url in the overview.

[image]

2.In the kudu, locate to the site folder and change add below codes:

Notice: you need delete all the files in the wwwort folder add password behind the user name as below format:

```
https://{username}:{password}@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git
```

Code:

```
 git clone {git url} wwwroot
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Well, I find backup & restore far more simple and effective. And does not involve so much steps. And do not understand why the downvoting, since I list a totally valid solutions!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve and how this is related to programming, but here is a bunch of info that will help you:

- [Azure Web App Cloning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-app-cloning-portal)
- [Backup Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-backup)
- [Restore Azure Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-restore)

Answer (score -1):

FTP client can be install on app server:
apt-get install ftp